# Svelte: check if parent is listening a custom event

Tags: events, svelte, svelte-component

I have a child component and want to check if any parent is listening to a custom event, so I can do something (e.g. creating a blocking mask for click), is that a way to do it?

`Child.svelte`:

```
...
const dispatchEvent = createEventDispatcher<{ click: void }>();
...
{#if $listeners && $listeners.click} <!-- syntax to check if any parent is listening to click event? -->
  <span>Listening to click</span>
{/if}
```

`Parent.svelte`:

```
<Child on:click={...} /> <!-- print "Listening to click" -->
<Child /> <!-- print nothing -->
```

P.S. I know `$$props` and `$$restProps` but they seem not apply to events.